# Find a pair $(A,B)\in M_n(\mathbb C)^2$ such that the rank of $AB-BA-I_n$ is $1$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, matrix-rank

> Let $n$ be a fixed integer greater than $2$. Find a pair $(A,B)\in M_n(\mathbb C)^2$ such that the rank of $AB-BA-I_n$ is $1$.

I'm not sure how to approach this. I tried to think of $A,B$ as matrices of linear operators on some $n$-dimensional vector space, but I don't even know what ideas I should use to find the corresponding operators.

Comment: $A=E_{12}$, $B=E_{21}$, where $E_{jk}$ is the elementary matrix with only one non trivial entry, that one equal to $1$, placed at position $jk$. This works for $n=2$.

Comment: Notice that $AB-BA$ has trace $0$. Therefore, $AB-BA-I$ has trace $-n$. You can start with a diagonal matrix $D$ having $-n$ in *only one* of the entries in the diagonal and zeros everywhere else. Then $D+I$ has trace $0$. Now, [every trace zero matrix is a commutator](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~wkahan/MathH110/trace0.pdf) and the proof gives you an algorithm to construct one such representation.

Comment: Consider $A$ of the shape $D\sigma$, where $D$ is diagonal, and $\sigma$ is a permutation matrix,  for instance corresponding to the cycle $(123\dots n)$ (or to its inverse, i have to write down). And let $B=\tau$ be the inverse permutation matrix. Now we can take $1,2,3,\dots, n$ on the diagonal of $D$. Then the conjugated diagonal matrix should have on the diagonal $2,3,4,\dots, n,1$, so that the difference is $1,1,1,\dots$, except for the last entry.

Answer (score 2):

Let $E_{i,j}$ denote the $n$-by-$n$ matrix with $0$ everywhere except one $1$ for the $(i,j)$-entry, where $i,j\in\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$.  Set
$$A:=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\,E_{i,n}\text{ and }B:=A^\top=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\,E_{n,i}\,.$$
Thus, 
$$A\,B=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\,E_{i,i}=I-E_{n,n}\text{ and }B\,A=(n-1)\,E_{n,n}\,.$$
Consequently,
$$A\,B-B\,A-I=-n\,E_{n,n}\,.$$